# How to parse multiple log files using logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have a few log files like below
data_log_01.log
data_log_02.log
data_log_03.log
data_log_04.log

Is there any way that I can parse these logs one by one using a single config file in logstash?

Comment: Any update on this? Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Forgot to upvote and accept. Your solution worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the [file input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) with a wildcard?

An exmaple configuration could look like this, assuming your log files are located `/home/of/your/logs/`:

```
input {
    file {
        path => [
            "/home/of/your/logs/*.log"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The `path` value has to be an absolute path! You might want to see the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-path) on using path.

Comment: :-  How to parse multiple log files having `different format` using logstash?

Answer (score 0):

In logstatsh you can read from two different microservices logs using the below configuration. It creates two different indices for two different microservices in logstash. You can analyze separate logs of each microservice and you can create a data view based on index format myapp-* to analyze logs aggregated logs.

```
input {
  file {
    type => "myapp-ms1"
    path => "C:/D_Drive/Dev/ELK/myapp-ms1.log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}.*"
      negate => "true"
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
  
  file {
    type => "myapp-ms2"
    path => "C:/D_Drive/Dev/ELK/myapp-ms2.log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}.*"
      negate => "true"
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}
 
filter {
  #If log line contains tab character followed by 'at' then we will tag that entry as stacktrace
  if [message] =~ "\tat" {
    grok {
      match => ["message", "^(\tat)"]
      add_tag => ["stacktrace"]
    }
  } else if [type] == "myapp-ms1" {
    mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][target_index]" => "myapp-ms1-%{+YYYY.MM}" } }
  } else if [type] == "myapp-ms2" {
    #Index name should always be lower case
    mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][target_index]" => "myapp-ms2-%{+YYYY.MM}" } }
  }
 
}
 
output {
   
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
 
  # Sending properly parsed log events to elasticsearch
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://localhost:9200/"]
    user => "elastic"
    password => "c8_Hm9ebCcGTB-_5YnZm"
    cacert => "C:/D_Drive/Dev/ELK/elasticsearch-8.6.2/elasticsearch-ssl-http/kibana/elasticsearch-ca.pem"
    index => "%{[@metadata][target_index]}"
  }
}
```